# PM2 (Node.js) not listening on specified port

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

I am trying to get a Node/Express application up and running on PM2.  I can start the application fine with this command: `npm start`

This starts the app fine on port 3000.

If I try to start the application with `pm2 start app.js` I get the following in the log:

```
{ online: true, success: true, pid: 10714, pm2_version: '0.8.15' }
2014-06-12T19:52:06.789Z : [[[[ PM2/God daemon launched ]]]]
2014-06-12T19:52:06.800Z : RPC interface [READY] on 6666:localhost
2014-06-12T19:52:06.801Z : BUS system [READY] on  6667:localhost
2014-06-12T19:52:06.978Z : Entering in node wrap logic (cluster_mode) for script     /home/user/test/app.js
2014-06-12T19:52:07.115Z : /home/user/test/app.js - id0 worker online
```

In my bin/www file I have the following specifying the port:

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

I have also tried running `export PORT=3000`

As well as the following in bin/www:

```
app.set('port', 3000);
```

If I run a `netstat -an | grep 3000` I get nothing back.

Comment: Well, you're setting it to `process.env.PORT` *unless* that's undefined, **then** you'd be setting it to `3000`. Did you try just `3000` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried that as well - it is still not listening on port `3000`.

Comment: That log output looks like what's from `pm2.log`, is there a log file for your application?  Perhaps within it you `console.log` something after the server starts with the host/port?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The answer to this, for anyone using Express, is to run this command:

`pm2 start ./bin/www`

I had been running `pm2 start app.js` which did not work.

Comment: And what is the difference here?

Comment: You saved me 2 days. It would be great if you can give an explanation.

Comment: Worked for me. Great. I am unable to find the correct answer anywhere else.
pm2 start ./bin/www

Comment: works for me...thank you very much!!! it was not working at 3000 either

Comment: This makes absolutely no sense.  How would ./bin/www have any idea where my sever.js file is?

Comment: @SephReed, i hear you. here's how i made it work (i.e.
`pi@myserver:~/nodeapps/expserver $ pm2 start`). if you had pm2 generate a file `ecosystem.config.js` in the project folder (the same folder in which you have `package.json`), change the line `script: 'app.js'` to `script: './bin/www'`.  
That'll hopefully retain all the other parameters in the ecosystem configuration file.

Comment: my hero........

Answer (score 3):

Your `app.set('port'...` calls are not directly relevant. `app.set` is just a place to store key/value settings but it provides zero functionality in and of itself. What you want to look at is where you call `app.listen` since that function is what accepts a port as an argument.

Comment: It looks like it is still set in bin/www - 

    var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
        debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
    });

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, with nginx configured as proxy server I couldn't see the Express app running by PM2. When I removed my `~/.pm2` folder it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I use this

pm2.json

```
[
{
  "exec_mode": "fork_mode",
  "cwd" : "/opt/acme_service",
  "script": "acme_service.js",
  "name": "acme_service",
  "restart_delay":"9000",
  "port"       : 8081,
  "node_args": [ "--acme" ],
  "error_file": "/var/log/acme_service.err.log",
  "out_file": "/var/log/acme_service.out.log"
}
]
```

"port"       : 8081 - accept port connection. same in app

```
var server = app.listen(8081 , '0.0.0.0');
```

Comment: Please explain how and why do you consider this to be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was listening in a specific port, but for some reason my interface could not find the host / port, then I installed NGINX and set the default, on  `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`, to:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection “upgrade”;
            proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
            proxy_pass ip:port/; <<<<<<<<< Change the IP and port >>>>>>>>>
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_read_timeout 240s;
        }

}
```

Check the last lines. The reverse proxy worked.

Obs: The `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` is included on `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, which is then used as the configuration for NGINX