# PM2 not listening on specified port

Tags: express, socket.io, pm2

when I type `$ pm2 start --name chat-1 chat.index.js -- --name chat-1 --port 8080` groovy it works, then when I do: `$ pm2 start --name chat-2 chat.index.js -- --name chat-2 --port 8081`
it still goes to port 8080.
I have attempted to replicate solving the issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24192971/pm2-node-js-not-listening-on-specified-port) however, cannot due to the poster not explaining how that solved the issue. 
I am using Express, Socket.io

in my app.js I have the variable set as:
`const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;`

Comment: you're passing the port as argument, not as environment variable.

Comment: I've been searching for a clearer example but all that I have been seeing is using a .env file (which I am already). when I use the `$ pm2 start --name chat-2 chat.index.js -- --name chat-2 --port 8081` is the .env file overwriting what I pass in through pm2?

Comment: Did you try :` $ PORT=8081 pm2 start --name chat-2 chat.index.js`

Comment: @JemHa I have not tried that yet, I will give that a try later and let you know how it goes, thanks for commenting!